# Class forward declaration libtorrent

Tags: c++, visual-studio, libtorrent

How is it I properly forward declare a class?

```
//client_functions.cpp
using namespace libtorrent;
session Sess;

bool Start_Client_Sess( )
{
    Sess.add_extension ( create_ut_pex_plugin );
    Sess.add_extension ( create_ut_metadata_plugin );
    Sess.add_extension ( create_lt_trackers_plugin );
    Sess.add_extension ( create_smart_ban_plugin );
    Sess.start_upnp( );
    Sess.start_natpmp( );
    Sess.start_dht( );
    Sess.start_lsd( );
    error_code e;
    Sess.listen_on ( std::make_pair ( 6881 , 6889 ) , e );

    if ( e )
    {
        #ifdef DEBUG_CONSOLE
        std::cout << "Start Client failed\n";
        #endif
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

the problem I have is how the code is there is only one `Sess` and that's how it needs to be as if `session Sess;` is declared in each client function a new session is created but now as `session Sess;`is declared outside of the functions then the application does not close properly as `Sess` has it's own threads and getting command line arguments from a second call to the application causes the second instance to hang.

I think I need `session Sess;` to be in `_tWinMain` but putting it there gives me errors on `client_functions.cpp` whare it complains that `Sess` is undefined.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but it's not how to forward-declare a class, btw.

Comment: 'session' is the class and its not recognised in 'client_functions.cpp' if defined in 'man.cpp' '_tWinMain'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of declaring `session Sess` declare `session *Sess` instead.  That way you can control the lifetime of `Sess` from your functions.  You can create it in e.g. `main()` and destroy it in a function that executes at the end.  To create it, do `Sess = new session;`and to destroy it, do a `delete Sess;`.

The downside is you would have to search/replace all the `Sess.` with `Sess->`.

BTW, it is more proper to use `extern` to reference a global variable e.g. `extern session *Sess`in every file except the one that actually declares it (probably the one that creates it, e.g. from `main()`.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want one global `session` instance shared by multiple translation units. What you can do is, in one translation unit/cpp file *define* Sess, like this (say this is your main.cpp):

```
libtorrent::session Sess;
```

In its header file (main.hpp), include:

```
extern libtorrent::session Sess;
```

In any other translation unit/cpp file that wants to use the session, make sure to include the header file (main.hpp), then you can use the instance created by main.cpp